# From human text to tree diagram (e.g. probability tree diagram) automatically

Tags: text, tree, diagram

I'm wondering if there is a way to create automatically a tree diagram starting from a human text. Maybe there is something able to do it, but with some limitations in the text format required.

I heard about algorithms which transform nouns and verbs of sentences in diagrams.

Comment: Is this about a text describing a diagram or do you want to create a diagram of the sentences and words? The former would be an NLP problem, whereas the latter mostly an NER and syntax problem. This will get closed if you don't make this a way more specific question, though.

Comment: Hello @Sebastian I'd like to create a **tree** diagram starting from sentences. The tree diagram is made by balls and branches; each ball represents an event (in probability), and on each branch there is the probability that the event on the right occurs (I said on the right because I'm considering a horizontal tree diagram).